# date data loading from backend set bootstrap datepicker in correct format

Tags: c#, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I use bootstrap datepicker plugin for my calendar and I have a little problem with formatting my loading data, I want to get my date format in this type `dd/M/yyyy = 15/Nov/2017` when my page loaded

Could you help me, thank you very much!

The Step 1) is my static HTML, 
The Step 2) when my page was loaded

> Step 1)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/M/yyyy" value="@Model.LiveDate">
```

> Step 2)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/M/yyyy" value="06.06.2017 00:00:00">
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bagratzakaryan/71qkge8x/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be like this. In some case, it looks like the first one, in the properties it should has `Value` method

> 1)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/M/yyyy" value="@Model.LiveDate.Value.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)">
```

In some case not has Value properties.

> 2)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/M/yyyy" value="@Model.LiveDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)">
```

Comment: So It is the correct solution. Thanks for @AkbarBadhusha

Answer (score 1):

Try setting value in the required format.
like

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/M/yyyy" value="@Model.LiveDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");">
```

Comment: `06.06.2017 00:00:00.ToString('dd/MMM/yyyy')`

It is the result

Comment: but now I have another issue could you help me? in the code I wrote like this format `dd/MMM/yyyy` , but the view I get this format `dd.MMM.yyyy` .
Why ?